# Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.CodeGenerators.GeneratedTagHelperContext

Tags: asp.net-core

I upgraded a Project from ASP.NET 5 Beta 7 to Beta 8 and I keep getting the following error which I am not able to solbe:

```
MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.CodeGenerators.GeneratedTagHelperContext.set_HtmlEncoderPropertyName(System.String)'.

Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.MvcRazorHost..ctor(IChunkTreeCache chunkTreeCache, RazorPathNormalizer pathNormalizer)
```

I have the following packages on my project:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta8",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Razor": "4.0.0-beta8-15575",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.Runtime": "4.0.0-beta8-15575",
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't mix beta8 (not digits after) with beta8-xxxxx. Either set all to `beta8` or all to `beta8-*`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Razor and razor.runtime.

I used this depenency

```
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta8",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-beta8",  
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.SecretManager": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta8",
```